# How to create CoreOS cluster on Google Compute Engine with kube-up?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, coreos

How should I create a Kubernetes cluster of CoreOS instances on Google Compute Engine with [kube-up](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/gce/)? I have tried the following, but kube-up times out on cluster validation and I cannot SSH into the created instances (keep getting asked for password):

```
export KUBE_OS_DISTRIBUTION=coreos
export KUBE_GCE_ZONE=europe-west1-d
export KUBE_GCE_MASTER_IMAGE=coreos-beta-991-2-0-v20160326
export KUBE_GCE_MASTER_PROJECT=coreos-cloud
./cluster/kube-up.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things

1) to get coreos kube-up working you need more things set

what I use

`KUBE_OS_DISTRIBUTION=coreos
KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING=none
KUBE_ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING=false
KUBE_GCE_INSTANCE_PREFIX=${USER}
KUBE_GCE_MASTER_IMAGE=coreos-alpha-960-0-0-v20160217
KUBE_GCE_MASTER_PROJECT=coreos-cloud
KUBE_GCE_NETWORK=${USER}
KUBE_GCE_NODE_IMAGE=coreos-alpha-960-0-0-v20160217
KUBE_GCE_NODE_PROJECT=coreos-cloud
KUBE_GCE_ZONE=us-east1-b
KUBE_SKIP_UPDATE=y`

2) it seems newer versions of coreos aren't getting ssh keys setup corrcetly in GCE. i.e. you can ssh into the core account (but that will only happen if you have `KUBE_OS_DISTRIBUTION=coreos` setup correctly, but gcloud ssh wont work, with the version of coreos noted above gcloud ssh will also work

Comment: Thanks, I had exported KUBE_OS_DISTRIBUTION and KUBE_GCE_ZONE, just forgot to add them. Why do you disable cluster monitoring and node logging though? Why do you need to set the other variables?

Comment: Also, how can I SSH into an instance directly, given that I haven't installed an accepted SSH key on it?

Comment: try the core account, it should have all ssh keys, for got to mention that,.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

```
export BUILD_PYTHON_IMAGE=true
export KUBE_OS_DISTRIBUTION=coreos
export KUBE_GCE_MASTER_PROJECT=coreos-cloud
export KUBE_GCE_MASTER_IMAGE=coreos-beta-991-2-0-v20160326

make quick-release
cluster/kube-up.sh
```

Note that BUILD_PYTHON_IMAGE=true needs to be set before make quick-release, it's because coreos master doesn't have python, which is necessary for using the salt.

Comment: I just tried on OS X, but building fails, presumably due to running out of memory (16 GB RAM).

Comment: really?  I build on an 8GB (linux)  laptop without any real problem.